# Mono package and problem with making game server running

Tags: server, mono, vps

I have problem with making mono startup with TerrariaServer on my vps.
I've installed mono-runtime and all "required" packages like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f mono-runtime
```

Then I made folder in /home directory to save there game server config

```
$ mkdir terraria_server && cd terraria_server
```

Then I've downloaded latest TShock server version and uzip it

```
$ wget https://github.com/Pryaxis/TShock/releases/download/v4.3.25/tshock_4.3.25.zip
$ unzip tshock_4.3.25.zip
```

And after all I wanted to start it with mono

```
$ sudo mono TerrariaServer.exe
```

But I've got that error

```
Can't find custom attr constructor image:
/home/thetanadu/terraria_server/OTAPI.dll mtoken: 0x0a000085 Unhandled
loader error: 8, (null) System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 (null)
* Assertion: should not be reached at loader.c:298

Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>   at OTAPI.Shims.TShock.Program.Main
(string[]) <0x0008b>   at (wrapper runtime-invoke)
<Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
<0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

        mono() [0x49ff2f]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7f975d676390]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x7f975d2d0428]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a) [0x7f975d2d202a]
        mono() [0x630409]
        mono() [0x63069c]
        mono() [0x630833]
        mono() [0x54357a]
        mono(mono_class_from_typeref_checked+0x223) [0x524c63]
        mono() [0x5234ad]
        mono() [0x560fb4]
        mono() [0x561354]
        mono(mono_metadata_parse_type+0x18) [0x5616a8]
        mono() [0x560e73]
        mono() [0x561354]
        mono(mono_metadata_parse_mh_full+0x1f8) [0x561e18]
        mono() [0x433fd6]
        mono() [0x500b39]
        mono() [0x501fbd]
        mono() [0x425db6]
        mono() [0x426749]
        mono(mono_runtime_invoke+0x3d) [0x5ac68d]
        mono() [0x5acace]
        mono() [0x461fc5]
        mono() [0x500b39]
        mono() [0x501fbd]
        mono() [0x425db6]
        mono() [0x42634b]
        mono() [0x4a11b1]
        [0x40e3517d]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your
application.
=================================================================

Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is my folder on the server - I think it should work fine because I have that "OTAPI.dll" there.

```
thetanadu@thetanadu:~/terraria_server$ ls -a
.   GeoIP.dat            OTAPI.dll      sqlite3.dll         tshock_4.3.25.zip
..  Newtonsoft.Json.dll  ServerPlugins  TerrariaServer.exe
```

I know that exe and dll libraries are for windows but mono should emulate that environment - right?

Edit - I installed package "mono-complete" and started working like charm :D probably latest mono don't have something important :)

Comment: Mono does not emulate Windows environment, it runs .NET applications. Please do not use `sudo` rashly, `sudo mono` should be never necessary.

Comment: I tried first normally then I thought - maybe I need root privileges to use mono - but nah. Do you have any suggestions maybe? Still struggling with this problem :/

Comment: And sorry for mistake with emulation sentence